# R joincount with non-integer counts

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spatial, weights

I am using the R function `joincount.multi` from `spdep` to look for spatial autocorrelation with my data. The joincount column is not an integer which is my expectation. I note that my adjacency matrix (from `nb2listw`) is not 0/1: the weights are 1/n, where n is the number of neighbours (so it sums to 1 over the rows). Is this weight what is causing my expected counts to be non-integer? Should I be using non 0/1 weights with `joincount.multi`? Thanks.

```
> joincount.multi(fx = as.factor(shape$CM_IMDRANK), listw = queen_shape)
      Joincount  Expected  Variance   z-value
1:1     744.036   164.140    25.342  115.1930
2:2     376.265   164.140    25.342   42.1374
3:3     297.374   164.240    25.357   26.4389
4:4     274.236   164.140    25.342   21.8699
5:5     242.895   164.240    25.357   15.6201
6:6     255.303   164.140    25.342   18.1091
7:7     248.142   164.040    25.328   16.7109
8:8     275.434   164.240    25.357   22.0819
9:9     323.426   164.140    25.342   31.6413
10:10   566.913   164.240    25.357   79.9664
```

EDIT:
Thanks to Robert's reply I have switched to binary weights:

```
      Joincount Expected Variance   z-value
1:1     4209.00   965.46   913.80  107.2983
2:2     2174.00   965.46   913.80   39.9793
3:3     1737.00   966.05   914.34   25.4961
4:4     1609.00   965.46   913.80   21.2887
5:5     1449.00   966.05   914.34   15.9717
6:6     1575.00   965.46   913.80   20.1640
7:7     1546.00   964.87   913.26   19.2298
8:8     1680.00   966.05   914.34   23.6110
9:9     1876.00   965.46   913.80   30.1212
10:10   3107.00   966.05   914.34   70.8031
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this weight what is causing my expected counts to be non-integer?

The observed behaviour is indeed related to the weights in your adjacency matrix.

> Should I be using non 0/1 weights with jointcount.multi?

**Weights and Join Count Statistics:**

- **0/1 Weights**: Join count statistics are often calculated using binary (0/1) weights, with 1 indicating the presence of a neighbour and 0 indicating its absence. When measuring spatial autocorrelation in a basic binary setting, this arrangement is usual.
- **Non-binary Weights (1/n)**: When you use weights that are 1/n (where n is the number of neighbours), you are interpreting the spatial relationship in a different way. In this case, each neighbour's influence is inversely proportional to the number of neighbours. This is a type of row-standardisation in which the cumulative influence of all neighbours equals one.

**Impact on Join Count:**

- **Non-integer Counts**: When non-binary weights are used, join count statistics that are not integers are produced. This is because the count is weighted by the fractional rather than binary values in your adjacency matrix.
- **Interpretation:** With non-binary weights, the interpretation of the join count statistic changes. Instead of just calculating the number of neighbouring pairs, it takes into account each neighbour's proportional influence.

**Recommendations:**

- **Compatibility**: The interpretation of the join count statistic varies when non-binary weights are used. It considers each neighbour's proportional influence rather than just the number of neighbouring pairs.
- **Binary Weights for Join Counts**: Consider utilising a binary adjacency matrix if your primary purpose is to perform a standard join count analysis for spatial autocorrelation. This will give you integer join counts, which is how this statistic is typically used.
- **Purpose of Weights**: Consider the purpose of employing 1/n weights. If the goal is to account for the varied influence of neighbours due to different neighbourhood sizes, this weighting system is adequate; nevertheless, it may be better suited for other types of spatial analysis (such as spatial regression) rather than join count statistics.

In short, the non-integer join counts you're seeing are most likely the result of your adjacency matrix's use of non-binary weights. Depending on your specific analytical aims, you may wish to adopt binary weights for join count statistics or stick with your current method if it meets your needs.